# Remove characters from file name in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

So I am trying to build a `Button` which is able to change the name of a file. In this case the files are images and what I want to do is remove what's before and including underscore. I was able to do it by simply using strings:

```
string a = "truck_0001";
string b = a.Substring(a.IndexOf("_") + 1);
label1.Text = b;
```

But now, I want to use it to remove something from a file name:

```
string caminho = @"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Teste\";
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(caminho);
FileInfo[] fi = dir.GetFiles("*.ico");

foreach (var f in fi)
{

}
```

Could you help me applying that on the name of the file?

Comment: `File.Move(f.FullName, Path.Combine(f.DirectoryName, b));`. See duplicate.

Comment: Use `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension` to get only the name and then use your `Substring` approach.